# How to ScrollTo after ScrollTo and ScrollToExact were deprecated

Tags: c#, android, appium

I have noticed that the ScrollTo was deprecated, but didn't find any good solution to scrollTo any webelement on page.

> Question:

can someone please help me figure out what's the best way to do that now in C#(Android device)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes your right ScrollTo after ScrollTo and ScrollToExact were deprecated, Please find the alternative solution here,

```
MobileElement radioGroup = (MobileElement) wd
                .findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()"
                        + ".resourceId(\"<your listview or any scrollview id>\")).scrollIntoView("
                        + "new UiSelector().text(\"+<your text>+\"));");
        radioGroup.click();
```

For more information please check this video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bT3tqaLNn-Y

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding the only method you can use to scroll is

```
driver.swipe(int startx, int endx, int starty, int endy, int duration);
```

You can likely build a `swipeTo` function using the method above and the following methods:

```
driver.manage().window.size().getHeight() // and .getWidth()
//Note I am recalling that one from memory as I do not have access to my appium program currently
el.getLocation().getX() //getY()
el.getSize().getWidth() // getHeight()
```

With a little bit of math you can likely turn these into a `swipeTo` method.